# WebForms Forms Authentication: Request.IsAuthenticated=false after successful log in and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I'm having a real bad WebForms day today!

I have a mature WebForms web application using Forms Authentication.  For some unknown reason my application has started to show `Request.IsAuthenticated` (on the `Application_BeginRequest` function in `Global.asax`) despite going to the login page, logging in successfully and calling `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()`.

I just can't work out what is going wrong.  Here are the checks that I have done.  I am hoping someone might point out something I've not checked here:

1. The authentication section of `web.config` is as follows:

   ```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="120" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="~/ExitPoint.aspx?Page=Home" />
   </authentication>
   ```
2. The authorization section of `web.config` is as follows:

   ```
   <authorization>
       <deny users="?" />
       <allow users="*" />
   </authorization>
   ```
3. For pages such as Login/Logout I have:

   ```
   <location path="Login">
       <system.web>
           <authorization>
               <allow users="*" />
           </authorization>
       </system.web>
   </location>
   ```
4. When logging in, I have breakpointed and stepped through the authentication process. This finishes off with:

   ```
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userID, createPersistentCookie: true); 
   // Includes call to SetAuthCookie()
   ```

where userID is a string value of "768".

5. An encrypted session cookie appears in my browser on the next request:

   ```
   Name=.ASPXAUTH
   Value=FFC592.....
   Expires=2016-05-16T15:41:58.817Z (basically "now"+1 hour)
   Path=/
   Domain=localhost
   HTTP=Yes
   Secure=(blank i.e. No)
   ```
6. Logging the `Request.IsAuthenticated` value in `Global.asax` `Application_BeginRequest()` method is outputting "False" (bool)

What else do I need to check to see what might be going amiss?
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is exactly what is to be expected. In the `webforms` request pipeline, the `AuthenticateRequest` event is raised after the `BeginRequest` event, so it makes sense that the request is not yet authenticated in the `BeginRequest` event.

See (for instance) [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx) for a description of the pipeline. Or just Google for `asp net webforms request pipeline` and you will find plenty of links...

Partial copy from the page I linked to:

1. Validate the request, which examines the information sent by the browser and determines whether it contains potentially malicious markup. For more information, see ValidateRequest and Script Exploits Overview.
2. Perform URL mapping, if any URLs have been configured in the UrlMappingsSection section of the Web.config file.
3. Raise the BeginRequest event.
4. Raise the AuthenticateRequest event.
5. Raise the PostAuthenticateRequest event.
6. Raise the AuthorizeRequest event.
7. Raise the PostAuthorizeRequest event.
8. ...

Comment: Thanks.  I could swear that `Request.IsAuthenticated` was showing up as true in the `Begin_Request` handler (once logged in) but based on the evidence you have presented and the actual effect I am getting, I must have been deluding myself!  Thanks.