# Microsoft Graph API Redirect successfully but Request.Authentication=false

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory, owin

After successful authentication for Azure AD in ASP.NET C# it, the home page is not getting in as authenticated.

```
 @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <h4>Welcome @ViewBag.User.DisplayName!</h4>
        <p>Use the navigation bar at the top of the page to get started.</p>
    }
else
    {
       //Its going in Else condition
        @Html.ActionLink("Click here to sign in", "SignIn", "Account", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })
    }
```

But when I see the log in the Azure for the status problem it says it success.

[image]

When I try to debug in Visual Studio Locally everything works fine it goes in the IsAuthenticated as true and works perfect. But the only problem in when we publish this in Production the problem arise as explained above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebForms Forms Authentication: Request.IsAuthenticated=false after successful log in and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255713/webforms-forms-authentication-request-isauthenticated-false-after-successful-lo).
But if you are using Dot net core then just Call app.UseAuthentication() before app.UserMvc(...) in Configure Method in your Startup.cs class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dot net core then just Call `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UserMvc(...)` in Configure Method in your `Startup.cs` class.

Also You can take a look at this thread [WebForms Forms Authentication: Request.IsAuthenticated=false after successful log in and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255713/webforms-forms-authentication-request-isauthenticated-false-after-successful-lo). But

Comment: Thanks will check and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but that didn't work with my project.. but my company at that time didn't want to use the azure login anymore. thanks once again.